# How to Replace "|" charcter in a mail id to "@" character using SSIS?and verfying count of delimiters in each row?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a flat file of 10 columns and each column is separated by a `|`(pipeline) character. In these 10 columns there is a column named `mail_id` where few rows under `mail_id` column will have pipeline character instead of `@`character i.e.., `abc|gmail.com` instead of `abc@gmail.com`.

How to change the mail_id column replacing pipeline character with "@" character. and how to verify if i am having number of pipeline delimiters in a single row are exactly 9.

How to work on above scenario using SSIS?

Comment: Use a different column separator at the source, one that is guaranteed to *no* exist inside the columns, eg: tab, § or ¤. Whatever your source is, it should be possible to specify a different separator

Comment: If you can't change separator then you can use Script task and go one by one row. If row has more than 9 separators, you extract `abc|gmail.com` from line (using separators position) and change to @. After that split all row. This applies if you have only one column, which can have this separator.

Comment: Hi Can anyone explain with the C# queryplease?

Answer (score 0):

Attach a transformation Script Component to your Data Flow and pass through all the columns from your file. 
Also don't forget to add your file as a connection to your Script Component.

Here is the method that you need to use:

```
//This is a standard method that you will find inside your Script Component
//by default input buffer is called Input0 and output buffer Output0
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
Row.mailId = Row.mailId.Replace("|","@");
}
```

Here it is, just try it and let me know.